# Loop through columns in Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe and would like to loop through all the columns and do some math function. But, unable to get the desired result.Below is my sample dataframe with 3 columns.

```
mydf=pd.DataFrame({'ID1':[9,3,7,5], 'ID2':[15,10,3,8],'ID3':[20,14,10,2]})

mydf

  ID1   ID2 ID3
0   9   15  20
1   3   10  14
2   7   3   10
3   5   8   2
```

the below is what I need to do for all the columns and it works perfectly. However, this is just sample toy dataset and I have over 500 columns in my actual dataframe and am trying to do looping through all the columns but it's not giving the desired result.

```
tmp_df=mydf.copy()

tmp_df['ID1']=np.log(mydf.iloc[:,0]).diff(1)
tmp_df['ID2']=np.log(mydf.iloc[:,1]).diff(1)
tmp_df['ID3']=np.log(mydf.iloc[:,2]).diff(1)
tmp_df

    ID1          ID2             ID3
0   NaN          NaN             NaN
1   -1.098612   -0.405465   -0.356675
2   0.847298    -1.203973   -0.336472
3   -0.336472   0.980829    -1.609438
```

Basically, I need the above result using a loop as

I have 500 columns to do

I've tried like this below:

```
for (i,j) in tmp_df.iteritems():
    #tmp_df['j']=np.log(mydf.iloc[:,0]).diff(1)
    j=np.log(mydf.iloc[:,0]).diff(1)
    print('Column:',i)
    print('Values:',j.values)
```

but, this loop gives values in list and also not iterating for all columns as I wanted. I think this can be done pretty easily but, am unable to get it work. Appreciate if anyone can help me with the efficient way of doing for all 500 columns

Expected Result using any Looping logic

```
ID1           ID2             ID3
0   NaN           NaN             NaN
1   -1.098612   -0.405465   -0.356675
2   0.847298    -1.203973   -0.336472
3   -0.336472   0.980829    -1.609438
```

Comment: `np.log(mydf).diff()` ?

Comment: anky_91: yes, I need that to take log and differentiate with 1 level above to the values. But, my concern is not about the math function but how do I get this done using loop efficiently as I can't code for 500 columns. Appreciate if you can help with that. Thanks

Comment: but why do you want a loop when `np.log` takes the whole df as input, did you try with `np.log(mydf).diff()` , it gives the same as your expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A way to do this is to use `apply`, no need to iterate rows

```
In [48]: mydf=pd.DataFrame({'ID1':[9,3,7,5], 'ID2':[15,10,3,8],'ID3':[20,14,10,2]})

In [49]: mydf.apply(lambda x: np.log(x).diff(1), axis='rows')
Out[49]:
        ID1       ID2       ID3
0       NaN       NaN       NaN
1 -1.098612 -0.405465 -0.356675
2  0.847298 -1.203973 -0.336472
3 -0.336472  0.980829 -1.609438
```

The result is a dataframe, so if you need to keep the result in a new dataframe, just set it as usual

```
In [50]: new_mydf = mydf.apply(lambda x: np.log(x).diff(1), axis='rows')

In [51]: print(new_mydf)
        ID1       ID2       ID3
0       NaN       NaN       NaN
1 -1.098612 -0.405465 -0.356675
2  0.847298 -1.203973 -0.336472
3 -0.336472  0.980829 -1.609438
```

EDIT: Adding more details to rename columns after the apply to answer OP comment

```
In [58]: new_mydf = mydf.apply(lambda x: np.log(x).diff(1), axis='rows').rename(lambda c_name: f'new_{c_name}', axis='columns')

In [58]: print(new_mydf)
    new_ID1   new_ID2   new_ID3
0       NaN       NaN       NaN
1 -1.098612 -0.405465 -0.356675
2  0.847298 -1.203973 -0.336472
3 -0.336472  0.980829 -1.609438
```

Comment: `apply` also loops through rows

Comment: MichaelD: Great, thanks a lot...it works as expected. Btw, can I rename the columns with any prefix after the apply function? Let's say I want to rename cols ID1,ID2,ID3 as new_ID1,new_ID2,new_ID3 etc

Comment: Thanks. But, for some strange reason, the rename doesn't seem to work for me even though I just copy/pasted your code. I checked all the quotes, parentheses etc and nothing seem to be off...Btw, my pandas version is '0.23.4'. new_df1=mydf.apply(lambda x: np.log(x).diff(1),axis='rows').rename(lambda c_name: f'new_{c_name}',axis='columns')
                                                                                                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: I'm using version 24.2 of pandas, but there should be no difference in the rename function.  Are you using Python 3?

Comment: Yes, am using Python 3 (3.5.6 to be more specific)

Comment: It just cut/paste into a new instance and it works.  What's the syntax error?